# How to use Bezier curve to model one to one functions?

Tags: derivatives, continuity, parametric, mathematical-modeling, bezier-curve

I recently have been looking at Bezier curves.  I thought it would be useful in modeling the continuous function across a series of plotted points.  So I started with
$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and real numbers $$x_0 < x_1 < x_2$$ where the domain of $f(x)$ is $$(-\infty,x_0]$$ and the domain of $g(x)$ is $$[x_2,\infty)$$ and we have real numbers $y_1, y_2, y_3$ each of which correspond to the data points $$(x_0,y_0),(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$$ and $$f(x_0)=y_0$$      $$g(x_2)=y_2$$
I want to generate to Bezier curves, $B_1$ and $B_2$ such that $B_1$ extends from $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(x_1,y_1)$ and $B_2$ extends from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$. I want to work within the limitation that
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0}B_1'(x)$$
$$\lim_{x\to x_1}B_1'(x) = \lim_{x\to x_1}B_2'(x)$$
$$\lim_{x\to x_2}B_2'(x) = \lim_{x\to x_2}g'(x)$$
I found the equation for the angle bisecting line running through $(x_1,y_1)$ for that is $$y=\left\{x_{0}\le x\le x_{2}\right\}\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)\right)}x+\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}y_{0}-y_{1}x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}y_{1}-y_{2}x_{1}\right)\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)\right)}$$
I figured that this would be relevant, but I am not quite sure where to go from here, other than the two starting curves $$((1-t)x_0+tx_1,(1-t)y_0+ty_1)$$ $$((1-t)x_1+tx_2,(1-t)y_1+ty_2)$$ where $0\leq t \leq 1$. Again, my main parameters are that $B_1$ and $B_2$ need to be one to one, and
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0}B_1'(x)$$
$$\lim_{x\to x_1}B_1'(x) = \lim_{x\to x_1}B_2'(x)$$
$$\lim_{x\to x_2}B_2'(x) = \lim_{x\to x_2}g'(x)$$

Comment: If you discover that you have two cubic pieces with a $C_2$ junction that satisfy your other constraints, then, in effect, you have re-invented cubic splines.

Comment: Constructing a cubic spline using the standard techniques (as described on the Wikipedia page I referenced) would be a **lot** less work than your current approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working through and I found a way to model the two Bezier curves I was looking for. Here is what I came up with; I used
$f\left(x\right)=\left\{x\le x_{0}:\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right\}$
and
$g\left(x\right)=\left\{x\ge x_{2}:\sin x\right\}$,
but any function works.
So then I have
$$x_0<x_1<x_2$$
and
$p_{0}=\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)$, $p_{1}=\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right)$, $p_{2}=\left(x_{2},y_{2}\right)$ where
$$y_{0}=f\left(x_{0}\right),y_{2}=g\left(x_{2}\right)$$
I then made some segments indicative of the slopes to frame the two Bezier curves.
$$m_{x0}\left(x\right)=\left\{x_{0}\le x\le x_{1}:f'\left(x_{0}\right)\left(x-x_{0}\right)+y_{0}\right\}$$
$m_{x1}\left(x\right)=\left\{x_{0}\le x\le x_{2}:\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)\right)x+\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}y_{0}-y_{1}x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}y_{1}-y_{2}x_{1}\right)\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)\right)}\right\}$
$$m_{x2}\left(x\right)=\left\{x_{1}\le x\le x_{2}:g'\left(x_{2}\right)\left(x-x_{2}\right)+y_{2}\right\}$$

The $m_{x1}\left(x\right)$ segment has the slope of the perpendicular bisector of $∠p_0p_1p_2$ and runs through $p_1$.  I set this up to maintain continuity of the slope from the first Bezier curve to the second Bezier.

So, after that, I set up 4 points on the segments.
$$a=\left(a_{x},a_{y}\right),b=\left(b_{x},b_{y}\right),c=\left(c_{x},c_{y}\right),d=\left(d_{x},d_{y}\right)$$
where
$$x_0<a_x<x_1,x_0<b_x<x_1,x_1<c_x<x_2,x_1<d_x<x_2$$
and
$$a_{y}=m_{x0}\left(a_{x}\right),b_{y}=m_{x1}\left(b_{x}\right)$$
$$c_{y}=m_{x1}\left(c_{x}\right),d_{y}=m_{x2}\left(d_{x}\right)$$

Using these points, I plotted in Desmos some basic segment curves to start with, given $0\leq t \leq1$, going from $x_0$ to $a$,
$$\left(\left(1-t\right)x_{0}+ta_{x},\left(1-t\right)y_{0}+ta_{y}\right)$$
$a$ to $b$,
$$\left(\left(1-t\right)a_{x}+tb_{x},\left(1-t\right)a_{y}+tb_{y}\right)$$
$b$ to $x_1$,
$$\left(\left(1-t\right)b_{x}+tx_{1},\left(1-t\right)b_{y}+ty_{1}\right)$$
$x_1$ to $c$,
$$\left(\left(1-t\right)x_{1}+tc_{x},\left(1-t\right)y_{1}+tc_{y}\right)$$
$c$ to $d$,
$$\left(\left(1-t\right)c_{x}+td_{x},\left(1-t\right)c_{y}+td_{y}\right)$$
and $d$ to $x_2$,
$$\left(\left(1-t\right)d_{x}+tx_{2},\left(1-t\right)d_{y}+ty_{2}\right)$$

Then, I took the whole $(1-t)*()+t*()$ principle to create curves from these segments.
$$
(1-t)*( x_0 \text{ to } a )+t*( a \text{ to } b )
=\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)x_{0}+ta_{x}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)a_{x}+tb_{x}\right),\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)y_{0}+ta_{y}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)a_{y}+tb_{y}\right)\right)
$$

$$
(1-t)*( a \text{ to } b )+t*( b \text{ to } x_1 )=
\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)a_{x}+tb_{x}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)b_{x}+tx_{1}\right),\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)a_{y}+tb_{y}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)b_{y}+ty_{1}\right)\right)
$$

$$
(1-t)*( x_1 \text{ to } c )+t*( c \text{ to } d )=
\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)x_{1}+tc_{x}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)c_{x}+td_{x}\right),\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)y_{1}+tc_{y}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)c_{y}+td_{y}\right)\right)
$$

$$
(1-t)*( c \text{ to } d )+t*( d \text{ to } x_2 )=
\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)c_{x}+td_{x}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)d_{x}+tx_{2}\right),\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)c_{y}+td_{y}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)d_{y}+ty_{2}\right)\right)
$$

The final two curves resultant from combining these are
$$
B_{1}=\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)x_{0}+ta_{x}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)a_{x}+tb_{x}\right)\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)a_{x}+tb_{x}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)b_{x}+tx_{1}\right)\right),\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)y_{0}+ta_{y}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)a_{y}+tb_{y}\right)\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)a_{y}+tb_{y}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)b_{y}+ty_{1}\right)\right)\right)
$$
and
$$
B_{2}=\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)x_{1}+tc_{x}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)c_{x}+td_{x}\right)\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)c_{x}+td_{x}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)d_{x}+tx_{2}\right)\right),\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)y_{1}+tc_{y}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)c_{y}+td_{y}\right)\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)\left(\left(1-t\right)c_{y}+td_{y}\right)+t\left(\left(1-t\right)d_{y}+ty_{2}\right)\right)\right)
$$

Cleaned up, we get two sets of parametric equations, the first describing $B_1$, the second describing $B_2$.

$$
x_{t_{B_1}}=x_{0}-\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)\cdot3t+\left(x_{0}-2a_{x}+b_{x}\right)\cdot3t^{2}-\left(x_{0}-3a_{x}+3b_{x}-x_{1}\right)\cdot t^{3}
$$

$$
y_{t_{B_1}}=y_{0}-\left(y_{0}-a_{y}\right)\cdot3t+\left(y_{0}-2a_{y}+b_{y}\right)\cdot3t^{2}-\left(y_{0}-3a_{y}+3b_{y}-y_{1}\right)\cdot t^{3}
$$
and
$$
x_{t_{B_2}}=x_{1}-\left(x_{1}-c_{x}\right)\cdot3t+\left(x_{1}-2c_{x}+d_{x}\right)\cdot3t^{2}-\left(x_{1}-3c_{x}+3d_{x}-x_{2}\right)\cdot t^{3}
$$

$$
y_{t_{B_2}}=y_{1}-\left(y_{1}-c_{y}\right)\cdot3t+\left(y_{1}-2c_{y}+d_{y}\right)\cdot3t^{2}-\left(y_{1}-3c_{y}+3d_{y}-y_{2}\right)\cdot t^{3}
$$

Now, all that is left is to prove that these two curves are one to one, and that $$\lim_{x\to {x_0}}{f'(x)}=\lim_{x\to {x_0}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to {x_1}}{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}
=
\lim_{x\to {x_1}}{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to {x_2}}{g'(x)}=\lim_{x\to {x_2}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}$$

To prove that the curves are one to one, we simply need to establish that as $t$ grows larger, so does the $x$ values.  That is to say,
$$\frac{d}{dt}{x_{t_{B_1}}}>0 \text{ } and \text{ } \frac{d}{dt}{x_{t_{B_2}}}>0$$

Taking the derivative with respect to $t$, we get
$$\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}=3\left(\left(a_{x}-x_{0}\right)+\left(x_{0}-2a_{x}+b_{x}\right)2t+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}+3a_{x}-3b_{x}\right)t^{2}\right)$$
Note that $x_0<a_x<b_x<x_1$ must be true or $x_0<b_x<a_x<x_1$  or $b_x=a_x$.  In the first case, we can rewrite $a_x$,$b_x$ and $x_1$ as

- $a_x=x_0+\alpha$
- $b_x=x_0+\alpha+\beta$
- $x_1=x_0+\alpha+\beta+\gamma$
  $$$$
  and in the second case we can rewrite them as
- $b_x=x_0+\alpha$
- $a_x=x_0+\alpha+\beta$
- $x_1=x_0+\alpha+\beta+\gamma$

where $\alpha,\beta,$and$\gamma$ are positive constants representing the differential between values.

1. Case 1
   $$\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}=3\left(\left(x_{0}+\alpha+\beta+γ\right)t^{2}+\left(x_{0}+\alpha+\beta\right)\left(-3t^{2}+2t\right)+\left(x_{0}+\alpha\right)\left(3t^{2}-4t+1\right)+x_{0}\left(-t^{2}+2t-1\right)\right)$$
   $$0<3\left(\left(x_{0}+\alpha+\beta+γ\right)t^{2}+\left(x_{0}+\alpha+\beta\right)\left(-3t^{2}+2t\right)+\left(x_{0}+\alpha\right)\left(3t^{2}-4t+1\right)+x_{0}\left(-t^{2}+2t-1\right)\right)$$
   $$0<x_{0}\left(\left(t^{2}\right)+\left(-3t^{2}+2t\right)+\left(3t^{2}-4t+1\right)+\left(-t^{2}+2t-1\right)\right)+\left(\alpha+\beta+γ\right)t^{2}+\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\left(-3t^{2}+2t\right)+\left(\alpha\right)\left(3t^{2}-4t+1\right)$$
   $$0<x_{0}\cdot0+\left(\alpha+\beta+γ\right)t^{2}+\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\left(-3t^{2}+2t\right)+\left(\alpha\right)\left(3t^{2}-4t+1\right)$$
   $$0<\alpha\left(t^{2}+\left(-3t^{2}+2t\right)+\left(3t^{2}-4t+1\right)\right)+\beta\left(t^{2}+\left(-3t^{2}+2t\right)\right)+\left(γ\right)t^{2}$$
   $$0<\alpha\left(t^{2}-2t+1\right)+\beta\left(2t-2t^{2}\right)+γt^{2}$$
   $$0<\alpha\cdot\left(1-t\right)^{2}+2\beta\cdot\left(t\right)\left(1-t\right)+γt^{2}$$
   2.Case 2
   $$\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}=3\left(x_{1}t^{2}+a_{x}\left(3t^{2}-4t+1\right)+b_{x}\left(-3t^{2}+2t\right)+x_{0}\left(-t^{2}+2t-1\right)\right)$$
   $$\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}=3\left(\left(x_{0}+\alpha+\beta+γ\right)t^{2}+\left(x_{0}+\alpha+\beta\right)\left(3t^{2}-4t+1\right)+\left(x_{0}+\alpha\right)\left(-3t^{2}+2t\right)+x_{0}\left(-t^{2}+2t-1\right)\right)$$
   $$0<\left(x_{0}+\alpha+\beta+γ\right)t^{2}+\left(x_{0}+\alpha+\beta\right)\left(3t^{2}-4t+1\right)+\left(x_{0}+\alpha\right)\left(-3t^{2}+2t\right)+x_{0}\left(-t^{2}+2t-1\right)$$
   $$0<x_{0}\left(t^{2}+\left(3t^{2}-4t+1\right)+\left(-3t^{2}+2t\right)+\left(-t^{2}+2t-1\right)\right)+\alpha\left(t^{2}+\left(3t^{2}-4t+1\right)+\left(-3t^{2}+2t\right)\right)+\beta\left(t^{2}+\left(3t^{2}-4t+1\right)\right)+\left(γ\right)t^{2}$$
   $$0<x_{0}\cdot0+\alpha\left(t^{2}-2t+1\right)+\beta\left(4t^{2}-4t+1\right)+γt^{2}$$
   $$0<x_{0}\cdot0+\alpha\left(1-t\right)^{2}+\beta\left(1-2t\right)^{2}+γt^{2}$$
   As we can see, both cases result in a sum of positive constants with positive coefficients yielding a positive result.  The case of $a_x=b_x$ is accounted for with $\beta=0$ That said, in order to obtain a positive $\frac{d}{dt}{t_{B_1}}$, $\alpha$ must be greater than zero, because otherwise at $t=0$ the whole derivative would equal zero.

As far as proving that
$$\lim_{x\to {x_0}}{f'(x)}=\lim_{x\to {x_0}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to {x_1}}{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}
=
\lim_{x\to {x_1}}{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to {x_2}}{g'(x)}=\lim_{x\to {x_2}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}$$

First I'll set up the parametric equations modeling the slope of the two Bezier curves.  To find that, we use for the new x values$x_t=x_t$, and the new y values $y'_t=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}{y_t}}{\frac{d}{dt}{x_t}}$

- Derivative of $B_1$
  $$x_{t_{B_1}}=x_{0}-\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)\cdot3t+\left(x_{0}-2a_{x}+b_{x}\right)\cdot3t^{2}-\left(x_{0}-3a_{x}+3b_{x}-x_{1}\right)\cdot t^{3}$$
  $$y'_{t_{B_1}}=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}{(y_{0}-\left(y_{0}-a_{y}\right)\cdot3t+\left(y_{0}-2a_{y}+b_{y}\right)\cdot3t^{2}-\left(y_{0}-3a_{y}+3b_{y}-y_{1}\right)\cdot t^{3})}}{\frac{d}{dt}{x_{0}-\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)\cdot3t+\left(x_{0}-2a_{x}+b_{x}\right)\cdot3t^{2}-\left(x_{0}-3a_{x}+3b_{x}-x_{1}\right)\cdot t^{3}}}$$
  $$y'_{t_{B_1}}=\frac{-\left(y_{0}-a_{y}\right)\cdot3+\left(y_{0}-2a_{y}+b_{y}\right)\cdot6t-\left(y_{0}-3a_{y}+3b_{y}-y_{1}\right)\cdot3t^{2}}{-\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)\cdot3+\left(x_{0}-2a_{x}+b_{x}\right)\cdot6t-\left(x_{0}-3a_{x}+3b_{x}-x_{1}\right)\cdot3t^{2}}$$
  $$y'_{t_{B_1}}=\frac{\left(y_{0}-a_{y}\right)-\left(y_{0}-2a_{y}+b_{y}\right)\cdot2t+\left(y_{0}-3a_{y}+3b_{y}-y_{1}\right)\cdot t^{2}}{\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)-\left(x_{0}-2a_{x}+b_{x}\right)\cdot2t+\left(x_{0}-3a_{x}+3b_{x}-x_{1}\right)\cdot t^{2}}$$

Right, as  we can see in the above equation for $x_t$ for $B_1$, $x_t$ approaches $x_0$ as $t$ approaches zero.  Also, $x_t$ approaches $x_1$ when $t$ approaches 1.
$$\lim_{x\to {x_0}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}=\lim_{t\to {0}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}=\lim_{t\to {0}}
\frac{\left(y_{0}-a_{y}\right)-\left(y_{0}-2a_{y}+b_{y}\right)\cdot2t+\left(y_{0}-3a_{y}+3b_{y}-y_{1}\right)\cdot t^{2}}{\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)-\left(x_{0}-2a_{x}+b_{x}\right)\cdot2t+\left(x_{0}-3a_{x}+3b_{x}-x_{1}\right)\cdot t^{2}}$$
$$=\frac{\left(y_{0}-a_{y}\right)}{\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)}$$
We established in the beginning that $a_{y}=m_{x_0}\left(a_{x}\right)$.
$$\lim_{x\to {x_0}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}=\frac{\left(y_{0}-m_{x_0}\left(a_{x}\right)\right)}{\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)}$$
and we established

$m_{x_0}\left(x\right)=\left\{x_{0}\le x\le x_{1}:f'\left(x_{0}\right)\left(x-x_{0}\right)+y_{0}\right\}$ so,

$$m_{x_0}\left(a_{x}\right)=f'(x_{0})(a_{x}-x_{0})+y_{0}$$

$$\lim_{x\to {x_0}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}=\frac{\left(y_{0}-(f'(x_{0})(a_{x}-x_{0})+y_{0})\right)
}{\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)}$$
$$\lim_{x\to {x_0}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}=\frac{\left(-(f'(x_{0})(a_{x}-x_{0}))\right)
}{\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)}$$
$$\lim_{x\to {x_0}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}=\frac{\left(-(f'(x_{0})(a_{x}-x_{0}))\right)
}{\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)}=f'(x_0)$$
So, the first limit matches up.  Next, as $t$ approaches $1$, $x_t$ approaches $x_1$  So, we calculate that out.
$$\lim_{x\to {x_1}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}=\lim_{t\to {1}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}=\lim_{t\to {1}}{(\frac{\left(y_{0}-a_{y}\right)-\left(y_{0}-2a_{y}+b_{y}\right)\cdot2t+\left(y_{0}-3a_{y}+3b_{y}-y_{1}\right)\cdot t^{2}}{\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)-\left(x_{0}-2a_{x}+b_{x}\right)\cdot2t+\left(x_{0}-3a_{x}+3b_{x}-x_{1}\right)\cdot t^{2}})}$$
$$=\frac{\left(y_{0}-a_{y}\right)-\left(y_{0}-2a_{y}+b_{y}\right)\cdot2\cdot1+\left(y_{0}-3a_{y}+3b_{y}-y_{1}\right)\cdot1^{2}}{\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)-\left(x_{0}-2a_{x}+b_{x}\right)\cdot2\cdot1+\left(x_{0}-3a_{x}+3b_{x}-x_{1}\right)\cdot1^{2}}$$
$$=\frac{y_{1}-b_{y}}{x_{1}-b_{x}}$$
Substituting $y_1$ and $b_y$ with values calculated from $m_{x_{1}}\left(x \right)$ we get
$$=\frac{m_{x_{1}}\left(x_{1}\right)-m_{x_{1}}\left(b_{x}\right)}{x_{1}-b_{x}}$$
$$=\frac{\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)\right)x_{1}+\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}y_{0}-y_{1}x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}y_{1}-y_{2}x_{1}\right)\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)\right)}\right)-\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)\right)b_{x}+\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}y_{0}-y_{1}x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}y_{1}-y_{2}x_{1}\right)\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)\right)}\right)}{x_{1}-b_{x}}$$
$$=\frac{\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)\right)x_{1}}{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)\right)}\right)-\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)\right)b_{x}}{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)\right)}\right)}{x_{1}-b_{x}}$$
$$=\frac{\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)\right)}\right)\left(x_{1}-b_{x}\right)}{x_{1}-b_{x}}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)}{\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)}$$
Which as mentioned earlier, was the slope of the perpendicular bisector I set up earlier.

- Derivative of $B_2$
  So, we do the same thing with $B_2$. Here we'll be using
  $$x_t=x_{1}-\left(x_{1}-c_{x}\right)\cdot3t+\left(x_{1}-2c_{x}+d_{x}\right)\cdot3t^{2}-\left(x_{1}-3c_{x}+3d_{x}-x_{2}\right)\cdot t^{3}$$
  and
  $$y'_t=\frac{-\left(y_{1}-c_{y}\right)\cdot3+\left(y_{1}-2c_{y}+d_{y}\right)\cdot6t-\left(y_{1}-3c_{y}+3d_{y}-y_{2}\right)\cdot3t^{2}}{-\left(x_{1}-c_{x}\right)\cdot3+\left(x_{1}-2c_{x}+d_{x}\right)\cdot6t-\left(x_{1}-3c_{x}+3d_{x}-x_{2}\right)\cdot3t^{2}}$$
  $$=\frac{\left(y_{1}-c_{y}\right)-\left(y_{1}-2c_{y}+d_{y}\right)\cdot2t+\left(y_{1}-3c_{y}+3d_{y}-y_{2}\right)\cdot t^{2}}{\left(x_{1}-c_{x}\right)-\left(x_{1}-2c_{x}+d_{x}\right)\cdot2t+\left(x_{1}-3c_{x}+3d_{x}-x_{2}\right)\cdot t^{2}}$$
  which we find using the same process for calculating parametric derivatives gone over with the first Bezier curve. In this case, we see that as $x_t$ approaches $x_1$, $t$ approaches $0$.  As $x_t$ approaches $x_1$, $t$ approaches $1$. So, we set out to calculate
  $$\lim_{x\to {x_1}}{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}=\lim_{t\to {0}}{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}$$
  and
  $$\lim_{x\to {x_2}}{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}=\lim_{t\to {1}}{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}$$
  In the case where $t$ approaches $0$,
  $$\lim_{t\to {0}}{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}=\lim_{t\to {0}}{(\frac{\left(y_{1}-c_{y}\right)-\left(y_{1}-2c_{y}+d_{y}\right)\cdot2t+\left(y_{1}-3c_{y}+3d_{y}-y_{2}\right)\cdot t^{2}}{\left(x_{1}-c_{x}\right)-\left(x_{1}-2c_{x}+d_{x}\right)\cdot2t+\left(x_{1}-3c_{x}+3d_{x}-x_{2}\right)\cdot t^{2}})}$$
  $$=\lim_{t\to {0}}{\frac{y_{1}-c_{y}}{x_{1}-c_{x}}}$$
  And similar to the case of $B_1$,
  $$=\frac{m_{x_1}\left(x_{1}\right)-m_{x_1}\left(c_{x}\right)}{x_{1}-c_{x}}$$
  $$=\frac{\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)\right)x_{1}+\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}y_{0}-y_{1}x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}y_{1}-y_{2}x_{1}\right)\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)\right)}\right)-\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)\right)c_{x}+\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}y_{0}-y_{1}x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}y_{1}-y_{2}x_{1}\right)\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)\right)}\right)}{x_{1}-c_{x}}$$
  $$=\frac{\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)\right)x_{1}}{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)\right)}\right)-\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)\right)c_{x}}{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)\right)}\right)}{x_{1}-c_{x}}$$
  $$=\frac{\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)\right)}\right)\left(x_{1}-c_{x}\right)}{x_{1}-c_{x}}$$
  $$=\frac{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)\right)}{\left(\sqrt{\left(y_{2}-y_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)+\sqrt{\left(y_{1}-y_{0}\right)^{2}+\left(x_{1}-x_{0}\right)^{2}}\left(x_{2}-x_{1}\right)\right)}$$
  As we can see, this is equal to the slope of $B_1$ as $x$ approaches $x_1$.  So far, we have established that
  $$\lim_{x\to {x_0}}{f'(x)}=\lim_{x\to {x_0}}
  {\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}$$
  and
  $$\lim_{x\to {x_1}}{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}
  =
  \lim_{x\to {x_1}}{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}$$

Now, in order to prove $$\lim_{x\to {x_2}}{g'(x)}=\lim_{x\to {x_2}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}$$ we have $t$ approach 1.
$$\lim_{x\to {x_2}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}=\lim_{t\to {1}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to {1}}{(\frac{\left(y_{1}-c_{y}\right)-\left(y_{1}-2c_{y}+d_{y}\right)\cdot2t+\left(y_{1}-3c_{y}+3d_{y}-y_{2}\right)\cdot t^{2}}{\left(x_{1}-c_{x}\right)-\left(x_{1}-2c_{x}+d_{x}\right)\cdot2t+\left(x_{1}-3c_{x}+3d_{x}-x_{2}\right)\cdot t^{2}})}$$
$$=\frac{y_{2}-d_{y}}{x_{2}-d_{x}}$$
And here we calculate $d_y$ using $m_{x_2}\left(d_{x}\right)$
$$=\frac{y_{2}-m_{x_2}\left(d_{x}\right)}{x_{2}-d_{x}}$$
$$=\frac{y_{2}-\left(g'\left(x_{2}\right)\left(d_{x}-x_{2}\right)+y_{2}\right)}{x_{2}-d_{x}}$$
$$=\frac{g'\left(x_{2}\right)\cdot\left(x_{2}-d_{x}\right)}{x_{2}-d_{x}}$$
$$=g'\left(x_{2}\right)$$
Thus showing that $$\lim_{x\to {x_2}}{g'(x)}=\lim_{x\to {x_2}}
{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}$$

In summary,

- $f(x)$ is a continuous function with a domain of $(-\infty,x_0]$ and a derivative $f'(x)$ with a domain of $(-\infty,x_0]$.
- $g(x)$ is a continuous function with a domain of $(x_2,\infty]$ and a derivative $g'(x)$ with a domain of $(x_2,\infty]$.
- $x_0<x_1<x_2$
- $y_1$ is a real number.
- $x_0<a_x<x_1$ , $x_0<b_x<x_1$
- $x_1<c_x<x_2$ , $x_1<d_x<x_2$
- $y_{0}=f\left(x_{0}\right)$ , $y_{2}=g\left(x_{2}\right)$
- $a_y$ exists such that $(a_x,a_y)$ lies on the line $y=f'\left(x_{0}\right)\left(x-x_{0}\right)+y_{0}$
- $b_y$ and $c_y$ exist such that $(b_x,b_y)$ and $(c_x,c_y)$ lie on the perpendicular bisector of $∠(x_0,y_0)(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2)$
- $d_y$ exists such that $(d_x,d_y)$ lies on the line $y=g'\left(x_{2}\right)\left(x-x_{2}\right)+y_{2}$
- $B_1$ is represented by the parametric equations
  $$
  x_{t_{B_1}}=x_{0}-\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)\cdot3t+\left(x_{0}-2a_{x}+b_{x}\right)\cdot3t^{2}-\left(x_{0}-3a_{x}+3b_{x}-x_{1}\right)\cdot t^{3}
  $$

$$
y_{t_{B_1}}=y_{0}-\left(y_{0}-a_{y}\right)\cdot3t+\left(y_{0}-2a_{y}+b_{y}\right)\cdot3t^{2}-\left(y_{0}-3a_{y}+3b_{y}-y_{1}\right)\cdot t^{3}
$$

- $B_2$ is represented by the parametric equations
  $$
  x_{t_{B_2}}=x_{1}-\left(x_{1}-c_{x}\right)\cdot3t+\left(x_{1}-2c_{x}+d_{x}\right)\cdot3t^{2}-\left(x_{1}-3c_{x}+3d_{x}-x_{2}\right)\cdot t^{3}
  $$

$$
y_{t_{B_2}}=y_{1}-\left(y_{1}-c_{y}\right)\cdot3t+\left(y_{1}-2c_{y}+d_{y}\right)\cdot3t^{2}-\left(y_{1}-3c_{y}+3d_{y}-y_{2}\right)\cdot t^{3}
$$

- The slope of $B_1$ is represented by the parametric equations
  $$
  x_{t_{B_1}}=x_{0}-\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)\cdot3t+\left(x_{0}-2a_{x}+b_{x}\right)\cdot3t^{2}-\left(x_{0}-3a_{x}+3b_{x}-x_{1}\right)\cdot t^{3}
  $$

$$
y'_{t_{B_1}}=\frac{\left(y_{0}-a_{y}\right)-\left(y_{0}-2a_{y}+b_{y}\right)\cdot2t+\left(y_{0}-3a_{y}+3b_{y}-y_{1}\right)\cdot t^{2}}{\left(x_{0}-a_{x}\right)-\left(x_{0}-2a_{x}+b_{x}\right)\cdot2t+\left(x_{0}-3a_{x}+3b_{x}-x_{1}\right)\cdot t^{2}}
$$

- The slope of $B_2$ is represented by the parametric equations
  $$
  x_{t_{B_2}}=x_{1}-\left(x_{1}-c_{x}\right)\cdot3t+\left(x_{1}-2c_{x}+d_{x}\right)\cdot3t^{2}-\left(x_{1}-3c_{x}+3d_{x}-x_{2}\right)\cdot t^{3}
  $$

$$
y'_{t_{B_2}}=\frac{\left(y_{1}-c_{y}\right)-\left(y_{1}-2c_{y}+d_{y}\right)\cdot2t+\left(y_{1}-3c_{y}+3d_{y}-y_{2}\right)\cdot t^{2}}{\left(x_{1}-c_{x}\right)-\left(x_{1}-2c_{x}+d_{x}\right)\cdot2t+\left(x_{1}-3c_{x}+3d_{x}-x_{2}\right)\cdot t^{2}}
$$

- $B_1$ and $B_2$ are one to one functions.
- $$\lim_{x\to {x_0}}{f'(x)}=\lim_{x\to {x_0}}
  {\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}$$
- $$\lim_{x\to {x_1}}{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_1}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_1}}}}=\lim_{x\to {x_1}}{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}$$
- $$\lim_{x\to {x_2}}{g'(x)}=\lim_{x\to {x_2}}{\frac{\frac{d}{dt}y_{t_{B_2}}}{\frac{d}{dt}x_{t_{B_2}}}}$$

Answer (score 2):

You have the following data that you want to match: a value and first derivative at $x_0$, a value and first derivative at $x_2$, and a value at $x_1$. You want a function that interpolates these values, and you want it to be $C_1$ continuous at the middle point $x_1$.

The simplest solution is a cubic spline with “clamped” end-tangents. This will consist of two cubic segments that actually have a $C_2$ joint at $x_1$. You can think of the two cubic segments as (real-valued) Bézier curves, if you want. Conventional Bézier curves are parametric curves, i.e. functions with values in $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$, so they’re not quite what you need.

In general, to construct a cubic spline, you have to solve a linear system of equations. But in your case the linear system will be trivially simple. Just look up [cubic splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)).

If you want to guarantee that the result will be monotone, or that it closely matches the piecewise linear interpolant, then life gets more complicated. There are things called “monotonicity-preserving” splines, and “splines under tension” that achieve these objectives. But, you might find that plain old cubic splines serve your purpose, without all this extra fuss.